# R Mysql help-need to do a calculation from variables in different tables

Tags: r, merge

I'm (very!) new to R and mysql and I have been struggling and researching for this problem for days. So I would really appreciate ANY help.

I need to complete a mathematical expression from 2 variables in two different tables. Essentially, I'm trying to figure out how old a subject was (DOB is in one table) when they were serviced (date of service is in another table). I have an identifying variable that is the same in both.

I have tried merging these:

```
age<-merge("tbl1", "tbl2", by=c("patient_id") all= TRUE)
```

this returns:

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

I have tried sub-setting where I just keep the variables of interest, but is is not working because I believe sub-setting only works for numbers not characters..right?

Again, I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `merge` statement miss a comma before all. If you have a unique shared varaible between tb1 and tb2 , no need to specify `by`: age<-`merge("tbl1", "tbl2", all= TRUE)` should work.

Comment: Thanks, agstudy! However, whenever I used your corrections, and added my connection, I get another error:

age<-merge(conn, "tbl1", "tbl2", all= TRUE)


Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("MySQLConnection", package = "RMySQL")" to a data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to data.base , I think you should use `dplyr` here. It is an abstraction layer for many data base providers. So you will not have to deal with db problems. Here I show you a simple example of where:

1. I read the tables from the MYSQL
2. Merge the table assuming having unique shared variable

The code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RMySQL)
## create a connection
SDB <- src_mysql(host = "localhost", user = "foo", dbname = "bar", password = getPassword())
# reading tables
tbl1 <- tbl(SDB, "TABLE1_NAME")
tbl2 <- tbl(SDB, "TABLE2_NAME")
## merge : this step can be done using dplyr also 
age <- merge(tbl1, tbl2, all= TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, again...agstudy. Now I'm receiving this error:

Error in UseMethod("tbl") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl' applied to an object of class "c('MySQLConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'DBIObject')"